# Error: libnode.so.64: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - node-rdkafka

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, node-modules, lib

So I get this annoying error:

[image]

I saw some posts talking about it, however, either they don't have an answer, or the answer didn't help me solving this error.  I had this error before, and I can't remember how I solved it.

This error came after I have accidentally removed the node_modules package, then I have re-installed it with `npm i my_app`.

I have already downgraded nodejs but I feel that playing with the versions is just a waste of time. Instead, I will be glad to actually know what's the problem and how to fix it.

- I have removed node-rdkafka from my project and it's working, so the problem is related to node-rdkafka. I can't find what is the reason that this is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`node-rdkafka` is a C++ addon it isn't installed as a vanilla js module.

in order to build this kind of addon you need to verify your environment

has C++ compiler, python and node-gyp properly installed

then after verifying the:

run the following command in your node project dir :

`rm -rf node_modules`

`rm -rf package-lock.json`

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm i`

then:

if the installation pass without any issue
navigate to :
`node_modules -> node-rdkafka -> build -> deps`

inside it should look the same has here except the file postfix should be .so instead of .dylib (i am using OSX)

[image]

now everything should work just fine

Comment: I have done all the commands, and have same package as you but still same issue.

Comment: Maybe the new version is behind all this? because I used the 2.13.0 version until today when I accidentally removed the node_module package.

Comment: I have resolved it by giving each package its own json package file. Somehow the node_modules package has linked to a false node_modules package so I removed it, then separated the big json package in main package to the packages. I think it's the correct way and it makes sense to give each package its own json package file. :)

Comment: Not sure i understand why you got more the one package.json file

Comment: Because I have a few subsystems and each has its own modules it uses. So it makes sense that each will have a package.json file for the modules it uses. Instead, what I did is to put one package.json file only in one of my subsystems to hold all the modules which are used by all the subsystems together, which is totally wrong.